# how to add and show wordpress category images without using any plugin

Tags: wordpress

https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/

i need exactly same functionality which one is using in this plugin.
but i want to do this without plugin kindly help me if any one have any idea.

i also try to upload images in folder and assign path like that

```
<img src"<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/xyz.jpg">
```

but this is not my requirement i need totaly dynamic. thanks.

Comment: if you are Lazy you should go with the plugin. If not you have 2 options: Write a plugin yourself. Or, upload a couple of images to your theme folder for each category and load the image when the category is beign used.

Comment: don't have any other option to do this like featured image ?

Comment: When you edit/add a category there is an option to upload an image. Would that not work?

Comment: after installing this plugin it will show, but i try to do this without any plugin. without plugin not showing any option after edit and create new category.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?